# How to suppress universe file path?

Tags: business-objects

My clients want to suppress the file path for the universe in the List of Available universes window in SAP-Business Intelligence 4 sp6 when creating web-intelligence documents.

Answer (score 0):

Can't. I opened a support case with SAP for this exact issue and was told the current behavior is "by design".